# Regex returns different matches based on what is executing the expression

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm using the following Regex: `(PatientID).*?[\d]+`

If I use Notepad++'s "Find In Files" feature executing that expression on a specific folder, I get 1118 matches in 231 files.

[image]

If I use C# to iterate over that same folder and get all files, I get 1070 matches in 223 files.

```
static string uat04Dir = @"C:\Users\me\Desktop\UAT04_Generated_Scripts\";

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Regex r = new Regex(@"(PatientID).*?[\d]+");
    int matchCounter = 0;
    int fileCounter = 0;

    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(uat04Dir, "*.sql", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        string lines = File.ReadAllText(file);

        MatchCollection matches = r.Matches(lines, 0);
        matchCounter += matches.Count;

        if (matches.Count > 0)
            fileCounter++;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} Matches in {1} files.", matchCounter, fileCounter));
}
```

Why is this returning different results?

Comment: In Notepad++, you are using a case insensitive search. In C#, the search is case sensitive. Try compiling the regex with `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`  flag and see if you get the same results.

Comment: How it should be: example http://imgur.com/a/gpVDA vs http://imgur.com/a/SBwvz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Notepad++, you are using a case insensitive search as the *Match Case* check box is not enabled.

In C#, the search is case sensitive, you are not using any options.

Compile the regex with `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` flag in the C# code, and it will yield the same results.

Comment: One of those mornings :) Thanks